# Difference between two's complement and sign-and-magnitude

Tags: binary

I'm just starting to learn about representing numbers in sign-and-magnitude and two's complement, and both as signed binary integers two's complement if representing a negative number I should invert all bits and add one, while sign-and-magnitude represents negative numbers with the first bit as a sign bit, but is it possible whether I can tell if a number is represented in sign-and magnitude or two's complement from just looking at it?

Comment: Only looking at binary you cannot even say is it signed or unsigned. Everything depends on interpretation. This is why we need types.

Comment: (*Only looking at a binary* representation of an integer I couldn't tell little endian from big endian, unsigned from signed. And in addition to *signed* and *two's complement*, there's [biased](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) and some more representations that have fallen out of favour (for a reason).) Interpretation is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every string of bits can be interpreted both as a two's complement or a sign-and-magnitude number. So the answer is clearly no.

[Usually, sign-and-magnitude allow negative zero; if not in your context, then you could say that $100\cdots0$ is a two's complement number, anyway.]